# Which sorting algorithm is most suitable for this characteristics?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Which sorting algorithm is most efficient to use when the underlying system takes trivial time to copy values, but way more to compare among them?
from insertion quick, heap and merge one

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms

Comment: Incidentally, with the marked dup, read past the accepted answer.  Another answer provides a better option for reducing number of comparison.    (And there is the tongue-in-cheek sleep-sort).